# Permission denied for virtual disk

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I try

```
[root@host1 81936aba-1f00-4fac-a69b-dfd69d290c3d]# qemu-img info 6c96bc5c-b6ac-442d-8581-2fb89f3d9a10
```

result:

```
qemu-img: Could not open '6c96bc5c-b6ac-442d-8581-2fb89f3d9a10': Could not open '6c96bc5c-b6ac-442d-8581-2fb89f3d9a10': Permission denied
```

access rights:

```
-rw-rw----. 1 vdsm kvm 1073741824 мая 11 19:16 6c96bc5c-b6ac-442d-8581-2fb89f3d9a10
-rw-rw----. 1 vdsm kvm    1048576 фев 16 14:38 6c96bc5c-b6ac-442d-8581-2fb89f3d9a10.lease
-rw-r--r--. 1 vdsm kvm        331 фев 16 14:38 6c96bc5c-b6ac-442d-8581-2fb89f3d9a10.meta
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you read this / does it help - https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/issues/996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo -u vdsm -g kvm
```

solved my problem